# My "exit(0)" function prints ": Success" to stdout. How can I stop this?

Tags: c, unix

I have googled already. I can't figure out what's going on.

**This:**

```
perror("some error message");
exit(0);
```

**will print this to stdout:**

"some error message: Success"

Comment: Is it really writing 'Success' to stdout? If you pipe the program to a text file (`./blah > out.txt`) is it still there (on screen, or in the out.txt)?  If it is, then are you compiling against any libraries or have 'exit()' redefined (perhaps a macro?)

Comment: `perror`:Error does not occur in particular. Last executed command is successful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `perror` prints out "Success", NOT `exit(0)`.

The reason is that before the call of `perror`, there is no error set (so the `errno` is 0 which is its default value when the program starts). So `perror` prints out `Success`.

check this

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/perror.html) for `perror`. `perror` takes an argument and prints it out followed by a colon and a relevant error message that might help to explain why something isn't working right. In your case, there's no error, so the only relevant message to print out is 'okay, everything looks fine from here'.

In the event of an error, you can test the value of [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) by including `<errno.h>`. If `errno` is set to anything but 0, this indicates a failure of some kind (which is why you'd then use `perror`). If it's set to 0, everything should be fine and `perror` prints "Success".

The proper way to use `perror` is to use it to print a meaningful error message to the user when an error is detected. For example:

```
char * c = malloc(1024);
if(c == NULL) perror("malloc");
```

The `exit(0)` is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

`perror()`: get a human-readable string for the error number, you can give format to the error message for something different than standard error output, if you don't define anything you get the "Success" message.

```
perror("some error message");  // prints "some error message: Success", because no error occurs.
exit(0); //exit with code "0"
```

More info [C perror()](http://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/stdio_h/perror.php) , [C++ perror()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/perror/)